# Mongoose lowercase flag is ignored while doing findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to store some fields in my documents as lowercase characters. Thus, I created a schema like

```
let body = new Schema({
    id: { type: Number, unique: true },
    group_name: { type: String, lowercase: true },
    type_name: { type: String, lowercase: true },
    full_spectral_class: { type: String, lowercase: true },
    spectral_class: { type: String, lowercase: true },
    spectral_sub_class: { type: String, lowercase: true },
    luminosity_class: { type: String, lowercase: true },
    luminosity_sub_class: { type: String, lowercase: true }
})
```

When I am using `save()` to insert values, all values are getting stored as lowercase strings. But when I tried to update using `findOneAndUpdate()`, the values are getting as is. I would rather not convert all the fields into lowercase manually as there are quite a number of fields and schemas following the same style.

Comment: You probably have to set [`runSettersOnQuery` to `true` when running the query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate).

Comment: That kinda worked. Using `runSettersOnQuery:true` in `schema.findOneAndUpdate(query, config)` didn't work. I had to use it as an option while defining the schema as [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the `runSettersOnQuery` to `true`.

```
const options = { upsert: true, runSettersOnQuery : true };
await yourModel.findOneAndUpdate(searchCriteria, newSetOfValues, options);
```

There are few samples on internet, but maybe you can find this one useful from [mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-lowercase).